# How to create a Linux GUI app short cut for WSL2 on Windows10?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have properly installed and setup WSL2. It works fine.
I also setup X11 forwarding and X server (VcXsrv). I can launch GUI apps such like konsole or gvim or even google-chrome from a bash shell.

Now I want to launch konsole by simply double clicking a short cut on the desktop without launching the bash command mode terminal. How should I do it?

I tried running this in cmd:

```
> wsl /usr/bin/konsole
```

and it reports:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

I'm guessing it is because some X11 forwarding configurations were not properly setup, so I created a k.sh as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
/usr/bin/konsole &
```

The first two lines were the X11 settings in my .bashrc, the last line launches konsole.

It works fine under bash environment; but when I ran

```
wsl k.sh
```

from windows cmd environment, it silently quitted without launching the konsole.

I'm out of ideas. What should I do to directly launch konsole or other Linux GUI apps under windows without having to getting into bash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a heads-up regarding the downvote (not mine).  While this probably would have been a better fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com) since it is just oh-so-borderline "programming", I'm personally giving it a pass since you are trying to determine why a *script* being passed in to WSL doesn't behave the same as it does when run from within the shell.  Scripting, IMHO, is on topic here.  That said, the downvote on the question is likely because someone else doesn't think it was on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about two different command-lines, and while the failures in running them via the `wsl` command have the same root-cause, the underlying failures are likely *slightly* different.

In both cases, the `wsl <command>` invocation results in a non-login, non-interactive shell where the command simply "runs and exits".

Since the shell is non-login/non-interactive, your startup files (such as `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`, among others) are not being processed.

When you run:

```
wsl /usr/bin/konsole
```

... the `DISPLAY` variable is not set, since, as you said, you normally set it in your `~/.bashrc`.

Try using:

```
wsl -e bash -lic "/usr/bin/konsole"
```

That will force `bash` to run as a login (`-l`), interactive (`-i`) shell.  The `DISPLAY` should be set correctly, and it *should* run `konsole`.

Note that the quotes probably aren't necessary in this case, but are useful for delineating the commands you are passing to `bash`.  More complicated command-lines can be passed in via the quotes.

---

As for:

```
wsl k.sh
```

That's likely a similar problem.  You are doing the right thing by setting `DISPLAY` in your script, but I notice that you aren't using a fully-qualified path it.  This would normally work, of course, if your script is in a directory on the `$PATH`.

But I'm guessing that you might add that directory to the `$PATH` in your startup config, which means (again) that it isn't being set in this non-login, non-interactive shell.

As before, try:

```
wsl -e bash -lic "k.sh"`
```

You could also use a fully-qualified path, of course.

---

And, I'm fairly sure you are going to run into an issue with trying to put `konsole` in the background via the script.  When WSL exits, and the `bash` shell process ends, the child `konsole` process will terminate as well.

You could get around this with a `nohup` in the script, but then you also need to redirect the stderr.  It's probably easiest just to move the `&` from the script itself to the command-line.  Change your `k.sh` to:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
/usr/bin/konsole
```

Then run it with:

```
wsl -e bash -lic "k.sh &"`
```

---

Finally, a side note that when and if you can upgrade to Windows 11, it will automatically create Windows Start Menu entries for any Linux GUI app you install that creates a `.desktop` file.  You can [manually create `.desktop` files](https://superuser.com/a/1679587/1210833) to have WSL create Start menu items for most applications.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, in Windows 11 it's easier. To run a GUI application without a terminal window popping up, you just need to call wslg.exe instead of wsl.exe.

So, for example:

```
target:       C:\Windows\System32\wslg.exe konsole
start in:     C:\WINDOWS\system32
shortcut key: None
comment:      Konsole
```

Comment: This question was specifically about Windows 10 and VcXsrv, so `wslg.exe` isn't applicable, since it only runs on Windows 11.  It also doesn't address the core issue that this question was asking about, which is that an environment variable that is set in `~/.bashrc` won't get passed through to `wsl.exe`.  Using `wslg.exe` doesn't change that.

Comment: I found it useful, however.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://aalonso.dev/blog/how-to-use-gui-apps-in-wsl2-forwarding-x-server-cdj) shows how to install **VcXsrv** and and edit *.bashrc* to ensure that the "*DISPLAY env var* is updated on every restart".

*DISPLAY env var* needs to be dynamic setting.

I've used it successfully with WSL2 on Windows10 Version 21H2 (OS build 19044.2130) to run Chrome, Edge, and thunar. I'm using the Ubuntu 20.04 Linux distro.

To edit .bashrc follow these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132247/how-to-edit-path-in-bashrc).